# Считаем, что отрицательные элементы разбивают его на группы. Найти группу положительных элементов массива с максимальной суммой

Tags: c++, массивы

что-то не очень работает
помогите

```
#include <iostream>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ukr");
    srand(time(NULL));
    const int n = 15;
    bool change = true;
    int arr[n], m = 0,p=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 10 - 5;
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] >= 0) {
            m += arr[i];
        }
        else {
            p = m;
            m = 0;
        }
    }
    if (p > m) 
        cout << endl << p << endl;
    else
        cout << endl << m << endl;
}
```

Comment: а по факту ошибка в блоке `else {
            p = m;
            m = 0;
        }` тут надо бы проверить что больше и только тогда присваивать.

Comment: @pavel да, все верно, теперь работает)

Comment: @VladimirGamalian не совсем понимаю о чем речь идет)

Comment: @pavel, оформи комментарий в виде ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в безусловном присваивании в блоке:

```
else {
    p = m;
    m = 0;
}
```

Тут надо проверить, что `p` меньше, чем `m`. Например, так:

```
else {
    if (p < m)
        p = m;
    m = 0;
}
```