# отрицательные элементы рабивают массив на группы, подсчитать количество групп у которых есть 0

Tags: c++, массивы

```
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ukr");
    srand(time(NULL));
    const int n = 15;
    int arr[n], m = 0,p = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 10 - 5;
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if ((arr[i] >= 0) && (arr[i] == 0))
                m++;
//      else
//          if (p < m) {
//              p = m;
//              m = 0;
//          }
    }
    if (p > m)
        cout << endl << p << endl;
    else
        cout << endl << m << endl;
}
```

Comment: Когда, по Вашему мнению условие в `if ((arr[i] > 0) && (arr[i] == 0))` истинно?

Comment: @andy.37 >= должно быть

Comment: @andy.37 но оно просто 0 считает, а не группы

Comment: Совет: выбирайте для переменных более осмысленные имена, чем `m` или `p`, Честное слово, проще написать с нуля, чем разбираться.

Comment: Вы лабы всему курсу тут делаете? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/549903/10105

Comment: @VladD та не,это мне одному, нужно до 00.00сдать, не успеваю. всего было около 45 заданий. срок на все - неделя

Comment: Четыре уже сделали [считай](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/215980/questions?fromdate=1469664000&order=desc&sort=activity&site=ru.stackoverflow&filter=!*Lgp2flMC8ig1iUN) )

Comment: @VladimirGamalian это последняя))

Comment: Поэтому вопрос с маленькой буквы начинается в отличии от остальных?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian не обращаю внимания на регистр

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ukr");
    srand(time(NULL));
    const int n = 15;
    int arr[n], m = 0,p = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 10 - 5;
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (!arr[i])
           m|=1;
        if ( arr[i] < 0){
           p+=m;
           m = 0;  
        } 
    }
    cout << endl << p+m << endl;
}
```